# How can I change a method to pass a proper object property?

Tags: java, oop

I have a method:

```
 public void dealDmg(int hp) {
        this.hp = hp;
        this.hp -= this.dmg;
    }
```

But when i use it as `dmg_dealer.dealDmg(dmg_receiver.hp);`, it doesn't work properly as in the dmg_receiver's hp is not decreased, but the dmg_dealer's hp becomes of the same amount as of the dmg_receiver, and then dmg_dealer's hp gets reduced by the dmg amount. How can I change a body of the method so that it works in such a way?

Comment: We can't guess what "doesn't work properly" mean. Please clarify the problem and what you try to achieve

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was clear from the `dmg_dealer.dealDmg(dmg_receiver.hp);` line. It changes the hp of the **dmg_dealer** object to the **hp** of the **dmg_receiver** and then decreases by the **dmg**, when I want the **dmg_receiver**'s **hp** to get diminished by the amount of the **dmg** of **dmg_dealer**. 
I try to make a simple game, so it's just when the attacker hits and deals dmg to the other character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass in the `dmg_receiver` object to the method instead of `dmg_receiver.hp`, that way you can update `hp` in `dmg_receiver` as well. The updated method should look like below:

```
public void dealDmg(DmgReceiver dmg_receiver) {
  this.hp = dmg_receiver.hp;
  dmg_receiver.hp -= this.dmg;
}
```

Comment: It would work, but this method is in a Unit class that gets extended by a few classes(Archer, Wizard, Warrior), so I don't really have a single DmgReceiver class, should I just "insert" a proper class object  into the DmgReceiver?

Answer (score 1):

If the object represented by `this` is dealing damage to another object, the `dealDmg` needs to the object being dealt damage to (assuming that `dmg` is a member):

```java
public void dealDmg(Unit other) {
    other.hp -= this.dmg;
}
```

Comment: this method is in the abstract class Unit that gets extended by a few classes like(Archer, Wizard, Warrior), and I don't understand how can i place that `SomeCharacter other`. Is there a way to link two extended classes through a method in their parent's method?

Comment: @heckfy88 I was missing the class names in the original question. If all the relevant classes extend `Unit`, you need to pass a `Unit` as an argument - see my edited answer.